# Cannot start MySQL on windows box with named pipes

Tags: windows, mysql, innodb

I've installed MySQL server on Windows although in the configuration have selected to not run MySQL as a server and have disabled TCP/IP access so only named pipes can be used, I'm now having problems getting the server running. Below is the output, after trying to start in standalone mode. Can anybody who knows a thing or two about MySQL make any suggestions on how I can get this running?

Thanks.

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin>mysqld --standalone --console
110723  9:09:54 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
110723  9:09:54 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
110723  9:09:54 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
110723  9:09:54 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
110723  9:09:54 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 107.0M
110723  9:09:54 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
InnoDB: The first specified data file D:\Work\MySQLDB\ibdata1 did not exist:
InnoDB: a new database to be created!
110723  9:09:54  InnoDB: Setting file D:\Work\MySQLDB\ibdata1 size to 10 MB
InnoDB: Database physically writes the file full: wait...
InnoDB: Error: log file .\ib_logfile0 is of different size 0 359661568 bytes
InnoDB: than specified in the .cnf file 0 56623104 bytes!
110723  9:09:54 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
110723  9:09:54 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
110723  9:09:54 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: INNODB
110723  9:09:54 [ERROR] Aborting

110723  9:09:54 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
InnoDB: The first specified data file D:\Work\MySQLDB\ibdata1 did not exist:
InnoDB: a new database to be created!
110723  9:09:54  InnoDB: Setting file D:\Work\MySQLDB\ibdata1 size to 10 MB
InnoDB: Database physically writes the file full: wait...
InnoDB: Error: log file .\ib_logfile0 is of different size 0 359661568 bytes
InnoDB: than specified in the .cnf file 0 56623104 bytes!
```

What looks out of place here is the complaint about ib_logfile0 being a different size. That will definitely take out InnoDB.

At the DOS Command Line, run this:

```
del D:\Work\MySQLDB\ib_logfile*
```

Restart mysqld and ib_logfile0 and ib_logfile1 should be rebuilt with the proper size.

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: Thank you! :) Sorry, some reason SA hasn't been letting me log into whe serverfault.com part. :S